# Java Memory Heap space issue in Open Shift Container

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, openshift

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space] with root cause

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Have you checked if there are [quotas](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.4/applications/quotas/quotas-setting-per-project.html#quota-viewing-quotas_quotas-setting-per-project) in place? Did you set any [limits or requests](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#resource-requests-and-limits-of-pod-and-container)?

Comment: Thanks Simon for Your reply . I have added requests .

Comment: It Looks like below .

Comment: "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "1000m",
                "memory": "2Gi"
              },
              "requests": {
                "cpu": "700m",
                "memory": "1Gi"
              }
            }
          }

Comment: So it seems that the Java program in your container is using more than 2G of memory. Make sure you configure the application to either consume less or set the JVM parameters (e.g. `-Xmx` or similar) so that the application does not use more than 2G of memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .We increase the memory but still it is failing with Java heap Memory issue .Could you please suggest how we can add JVM paarmters in Openshift container configuration ..

Comment: Hard to say, I do not know what kind of container image you are using or what kind of program you are starting. So you might want to check the above questions for your specific container.